# How to swap Laravel implementation with Behat and Mockery

Tags: laravel, behat, mockery

I have a Behat `FeatureContext` for which I want to swap a Laravel implementation of a given class with a mocked one.

so I have this method, with a `@beforeSuite` annotation

```
/**
     * @static
     * @beforeSuite
     */
    public static function mockData()
    {
        $unitTesting = true;
        $testEnvironment = 'acceptance';

        $app = require_once __DIR__.'/../../../bootstrap/start.php';
        $app->boot();

        $fakeDataRetriever = m::mock('My\Data\Api\Retriever');


        $fakeData = [
           'fake_name' => 'fake_value'
        ];

        $fakeDataRetriever->shouldReceive('getData')->andReturn($fakeData);

        $app->instance('My\Data\Api\Retriever', $fakeDataRetriever);

    }
```

So I see the Laravel app and the fake data being swapped, but when I run Behat, it is being ignored, meaning Laravel is using the actual implementation instead of the fake one.

I'm using **Laravel 4.2**

Does someone know a way to swap Laravel implementations when running Behat?

The reason I need this is because the data is coming from remote API and I want the test to run without hitting the API.

Comment: Where you are using `My\Data\Api\Retriever`, are you injecting it?

Comment: yes, I am injecting it in a controller which the test is hitting

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not too familiar with Behat besides what I just read in a quick tutorial to see if I can help found here... http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/laravel-bdd-and-you-lets-get-started--cms-22155

It looks like you are creating a new instance of Laravel, setting an instance implementation inside of it, then you are not doing anything with the Laravel instance.  What's likely happening next is the testing environment is then going ahead and using its own instance of Laravel to run the tests on.

```
use Behat\Behat\Context\SnippetAcceptingContext;
use Behat\Gherkin\Node\PyStringNode;
use Behat\Gherkin\Node\TableNode;

use PHPUnit_Framework_Assert as PHPUnit;
use Symfony\Component\DomCrawler\Crawler;

use Illuminate\Foundation\Testing\ApplicationTrait;

/**
 * Behat context class.
 */
class LaravelFeatureContext implements SnippetAcceptingContext
{
    /**
     * Responsible for providing a Laravel app instance.
     */
    use ApplicationTrait;

    /**
     * Initializes context.
     *
     * Every scenario gets its own context object.
     * You can also pass arbitrary arguments to the context constructor through behat.yml.
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
    }

    /**
     * @BeforeScenario
     */
    public function setUp()
    {
        if ( ! $this->app)
        {
            $this->refreshApplication();
        }
    }

    /**
     * Creates the application.
     *
     * @return \Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\HttpKernelInterface
     */
    public function createApplication()
    {
        $unitTesting = true;

        $testEnvironment = 'testing';

        return require __DIR__.'/../../bootstrap/start.php';
    }

    /**
     * @static
     * @beforeSuite
     */
    public function mockData()
    {
        $fakeDataRetriever = m::mock('My\Data\Api\Retriever');

        $fakeData = [
            'fake_name' => 'fake_value'
        ];

        $fakeDataRetriever->shouldReceive('getData')->andReturn($fakeData);

        $this->app->instance('My\Data\Api\Retriever', $fakeDataRetriever);
    }
}
```